# Using nested package type as type's private part declaration

Tags: nested, package, declaration, ada

```
package P is
   type T is private;
private
   package NP is
      type T is null record;
   end NP;
end P;
```

It is possible to use NP.T as full declaration of P.T?

Comment: P.T and P.NP.T are different type declarations (eventually of different actual types). Then you need one more line to do what you want to do.

Comment: I have several instances of the generic package in which types are created. I don't want to declare these packages in the visible part so as not to break the encapsulation, but instead provide functions to access them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is declare `P.T` in terms of `NP.T` as shown below.

**p.ads**

```
package P is
   
   type T is private;
   
private
   
   package NP is
      type T is null record;
   end NP;
   
   type T is new NP.T;
   
end P;
```

Comment: Such conversions require no action at run-time and so should not affect performance.